# Creating a multidimensional array using an array and loop through mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a table with the following structure. There are currently 9 students enrolled in 3 classes (classes 01, 16 and 52), with 3 enrollments in each class.

```
studentcode | classcode  
-------------------------
D3kcIvyp    | 01  
DdIhBc      | 01  
2vx0KV      | 01  
9p1PxWCV    | 52  
RnmfH1WE    | 52  
MSTBEv      | 52  
Yp4J3o      | 16  
fWQ5Oo      | 16  
6sxw3u      | 16
```

This is the array with all current classes:

```
$classes_array = array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 52 [2] => 16 )
```

Using this array I would like to go through the mysql table and create a multidimensional array with the classcodes used as first level keys:

```
Array
(
    [01] => Array
        (
            [0] => D3kcIvyp
            [1] => DdIhBc
            [2] => 2vx0KV
        )

    [52] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9p1PxWCV
            [1] => RnmfH1WE
            [2] => MSTBEv
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => Yp4J3o
            [1] => fWQ5Oo
            [2] => 6sxw3u
        )
)


foreach ($classes_array as $key => $value)
{

    $sql = "SELECT studentcode FROM table WHERE classcode = '$classes_array[$key]'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die();
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $studentcodes_array[] = $data['studentcode'];
    }

    foreach ($studentcodes_array as $studentcodeskey => $studentcodesvalue)
    {
        $multid_array[$value][] = $studentcodesvalue;
    }
}
```

Using the code above, unfortunately I don't get the array I would like to get. I get this instead:

```
Array
(
    [01] => Array
        (
            [0] => D3kcIvyp
            [1] => DdIhBc
            [2] => 2vx0KV
        )

    [52] => Array
        (
            [0] => D3kcIvyp
            [1] => DdIhBc
            [2] => 2vx0KV
            [3] => 9p1PxWCV
            [4] => RnmfH1WE
            [5] => MSTBEv
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => D3kcIvyp
            [1] => DdIhBc
            [2] => 2vx0KV
            [3] => 9p1PxWCV
            [4] => RnmfH1WE
            [5] => MSTBEv
            [6] => Yp4J3o
            [7] => fWQ5Oo
            [8] => 6sxw3u
        )

)
```

What is wrong with my code? Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate question. Look on right side of screen under Related

Comment: Hi Drew, I am sorry but I already checked on some questions.. but cannot find any answers to my problem.

Comment: Fair enough then thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You never initialise `$studentcodes_array` so it is remembering all the values from your previous loops.

Try adding `$studentcodes_array = array();` before your `while`.

Comment: Hi James! That solved my problem. I probably would have tried for ages.. Thanks a lot!